# Netty server remote connection

Tags: java, networking, netty

Netty server, Fedora. I just can't connect to the server from remote host and no listening socket is displayed via `netstat` util. However I can establish the connection running client and server on the same machine. That's simply like that:

```
port = System.getProperty(PORT_PROPERTY);
Preconditions.checkNotNull(port, "Network error, port property is not set");
hostAddress = new InetSocketAddress(Integer.valueOf(port));
...
serverChannel = bootstrap.bind(hostAddress);
```

I've tried initializing `hostAddress` with the port only, localhost IP, 0.0.0.0 IP, and IP of my network. Nothing helps. What could be the root of problem?

Comment: Can you ping the netty server remotely by IP address ?

Comment: @Nicholas, yes I can successfully ping the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's some suggestions that should help disagnosing the problem:

- For clarity (until you resolve this), stick to using

`new InetSocketAddress("0.0.0.0", Integer.valueOf(port))`

since this will ensure you bind to all interfaces.

- Invoke the JVM with **-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true** to force the JVM into IPV4. I have found it easier to muck with these issues when in IPV4 since is it less complicated than V6.
- Get the **PID** of the JVM and then issue a netstat like this:

`sudo netstat -ap --numeric-ports | grep <PID>`

This should display all sockets for your JVM instance.  (Please post this output if you're still not able to connect remotely. Also post the output of **ifconfig**)

Comment: @Nickolas, THANK YOU VERY MUCH!!!
The world could be much better if there were more people like you!
GOOD LUCK, GREAT MOOD, MUCH FUN!